# How to fetch data from complex JSON using java

Tags: java, android, json

I'm new to android app development and I am struck as I can't fetch the specific data which I need from a JSON.

Here's the JSON file.

```
{
  "message": "",
  "cod": "200",
  "city_id": 4887398,
  "calctime": 0.0863,
  "cnt": 4,
  "list": [
    {
      "main": {
        "temp": 268.987,
        "temp_min": 268.987,
        "temp_max": 268.987,
        "pressure": 1001.11,
        "sea_level": 1024.68,
        "grnd_level": 1001.11,
        "humidity": 100
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 5.06,
        "deg": 291.002
      },
      "clouds": {
        "all": 48
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 802,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "scattered clouds",
          "icon": "03d"
        }
      ],
      "dt": 1485703465
    },
    {
      "main": {
        "temp": 268.097,
        "temp_min": 268.097,
        "temp_max": 268.097,
        "pressure": 1003.57,
        "sea_level": 1027.08,
        "grnd_level": 1003.57,
        "humidity": 100
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 8.56,
        "deg": 314.007
      },
      "clouds": {
        "all": 44
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 802,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "scattered clouds",
          "icon": "03d"
        }
      ],
      "dt": 1485730032
    },
    {
      "main": {
        "temp": 266.787,
        "temp_min": 266.787,
        "temp_max": 266.787,
        "pressure": 1005.73,
        "sea_level": 1029.63,
        "grnd_level": 1005.73,
        "humidity": 100
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 6.79,
        "deg": 316.012
      },
      "clouds": {
        "all": 0
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 800,
          "main": "Clear",
          "description": "Sky is Clear",
          "icon": "01n"
        }
      ],
      "dt": 1485755383
    },
    {
      "main": {
        "temp": 263.64,
        "pressure": 1015,
        "humidity": 57,
        "temp_min": 262.15,
        "temp_max": 265.15
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 2.6,
        "deg": 280
      },
      "clouds": {
        "all": 1
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 800,
          "main": "Clear",
          "description": "sky is clear",
          "icon": "01n"
        }
      ],
      "dt": 1485780512
    }
  ]
}
```

What I am trying to fetch is **main and description from weather object of all the values** for example I'm trying to print this on my screen.How do I loop to get this result?.

```
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "scattered clouds",
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "scattered clouds",
          "main": "Clear",
          "description": "Sky is Clear",
          "main": "Clear",
          "description": "Sky is Clear",
```

Thank You

Comment: You can use JSON library like Gson to map json data to java object and iterate through the main array.

Comment: I am not able to loop through the second array, this Json contains subarrays.I have successfully fetched and printed the values of the main outer array but I am struck in the looping portion of the subarrays. I create objects using the tradational JSONObject class.

Comment: use this site http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ , copy your json and download the pojos. It should be clear to you on how to navigate through the object structure to print   what you want there.

Comment: There are cases where array `weather` has multiple elements? If yes, do you want to print all of them? Or just first?

Comment: I mentioned that in bold in my question "main and description from weather object of all the values" i.e for all the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using Jackson.

For your app you need these libs:

- Jackson Databind:
  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.11.1
- Jackson Core:
  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.11.1

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

    String json = "your json as string";

    JsonNode root = (new ObjectMapper()).readTree(json); //JsonProcessingException

    //check if root has node list
    if(root.has("list")){

        //get node list from root
        JsonNode list = root.get("list");

        //check if list is an array node
        if(list.isArray()){

            //iterate list
            for(JsonNode listElem : list){

                //check if current node fromt list has node weather
                if(listElem.has("weather")){

                    //get node weather
                    JsonNode weather = listElem.get("weather");

                    //check if weather is array
                    if(weather.isArray()){

                        for(JsonNode weatherElem : weather){

                            if(weatherElem.has("main") && weatherElem.has("description")){

                                System.out.println(weatherElem.get("main") + " - " + weatherElem.get("description"));

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

But if you are sure the json structure is the same all the time. You can skip all checks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

    String json = "your json as string";

    JsonNode root = (new ObjectMapper()).readTree(json); //JsonProcessingException

    for(JsonNode listElem : root.get("list")){

        for(JsonNode weatherElem : listElem.get("weather")) {

            System.out.println(weatherElem.get("main") + " - " + weatherElem.get("description"));

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This will get the required parameters for the 1st element, I need the main and decription elements values  from all the weather elements in the JSON.

Comment: @RandyOrton I edited my answer. Let me know if now is what you want.

Comment: Thank you @KunLun great help.